# Show that $y=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+2e^x$ is a 2 parameter family of solutions of the differential equation $y''+3y'+2y-12e^x=0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that $$y=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+2e^x$$ is a 2 parameter family of solutions of the differential equation $$y''+3y'+2y-12e^x=0.$$

I try this as followed:
\begin{align}
y&=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+2e^x
\\
y'&=-2c_1e^{-2x}-c_2e^{-x}+2e^x
\\
y''&=4c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+2e^x
\end{align}
Substituting these into the differential equation

$$4c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+2e^x+3(-2c_1e^{-2x}-c_2e^{-x}+2e^x)+2(c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+2e^x)-12e^{x}=0$$
It is here that I cannot turn the left hand side to be zero.

Can you check up whether my differentiation is correct?

Comment: I don't think you're substituting in correctly. The $y''$ looks right, but where did the $-3$ come from for $ey'?$

Comment: I see you've edited your DE correctly, now. You're subtracting $3y'$ instead of adding it.

Comment: I miss type the differential equation, it should be $y′′+3y′+2y−12ex=0$. Sorry, my bad. It is an excercise from Pollard's book of differential equation.

Comment: Looks like it all works out, now!

Comment: I finally made it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

An easier way to check is to verify that $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-2x}$ satisfy the homogeneous equation while $-12e^{x}$ satisfies the inhomogeneous equation.